# For a quadrilateral, if 2 adjacent sides are equal, and 2 opposite angles are 90 degrees, can we say that the quadrilateral is a parallelogram?

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, quadrilateral

> For a quadrilateral, if 2 adjacent sides are equal, and 2 opposite angles are equal (90 degrees), can we say that the quadrilateral is a parallelogram ?

I feel intuitively it should, but is there any formal way to prove this ?

Comment: A parallelogram with two equal adjacent sides and two right angles would be a square. Your conditions are not enough for that, try drawing a few figures.

Comment: @dxiv, conditions are enough ? I don't get it. If we have a quadrilateral with two equal adjacent sides, and two right angles which happen to opposite angles, one condition of being a parallelogram is met. Is it sufficient to say that is a parallelogram then or is it necessary to prove that opposite sides are equal as well ?

Comment: The conditions are *not* enough. There exist quadrilaterals which are *not* parallelograms that have two equal adjacent sides and two opposite right angles.

Comment: Ohkay. That's what I had a doubt about.